# Apache loadbalancing - how to get reported about server fault

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, failover

I am a newbie about load balancing so sorry if the question is trivial. I set up a basic load balancing using one server as a load balancer (planning to add at least one more with heartbeat) and for now 2 backend servers. It was done using mod_proxy (load balancing https requests).

What I can not find out is how to get automatically notified - for example trough email if one of the backend servers is down or not responding. Is there a way or I have to use external utility for it?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: As far as I know, the only "notification" apache would generate, will be on the error_log, with a line stating that it could not connect to the remote server (an probably a 504 error to the client). You could monitor your error_log, but you will get alerts once a client has encountered a problem, but I would rather run a script to test the remote servers beforehand (like every minute or so) to check they are responding correctly.

Comment: Typically I would expect my monitoring solution to: 1) detect the same outages that would be detected by the loadbalancer 2) send the correct alerts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if this is wrong since I didn't play around with heartbeat for a long time but when I last used it I just had to add `MailTo::name@domain.com::SUBJECT` to /etc/ha.d/haresources, where SUBJECT can be exchanged with the subject those mails shall have and your e-mail-address obviously. You can add multiple recipients by comma separation like this: `MailTo::user1@domain.com,user2@domain.com::SUBJECT`

Of course for this to work you must have "mail" installed and if you want to use an external mail-server you would like to also install ssmtp and configure it via /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf like this (edit it according to your settings):

```
root=your@email.com
mailhub=smtp.yourmailserver.com:587
AuthUser=yourmailusername
AuthPass=yourmailuserpassword
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

Comment: It is good to know, that I can set up this way two frontend loadbalancer servers, where heartbeat is running. But the main question is, how the frontend can report, that there is a problem with one of the backends.